# PXE boot hangs after PXE menu

Tags: linux, boot, pxe

My usecase is to install RHEL on a machine through PXE boot. I could do this with the standard RHEL OS and also automated installation with kickstart file.

Problem comes when I am trying to do the same from an RHEL image(customised OS with application data) instead of standard OS. I am using the same procedure and also able to see the PXE menu. But, when I click on it nothing happens.
I would like to know how can I debug the issue and any help in understanding the boot flow from files perspective would be greatly appreciated.

I am using DNSMASQ as a proxy DHCP server as I don't have access to actual DHCP server.

Below is my configuration file

# cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
port=0 log-dhcp dhcp-range=192.168.100.0,proxy dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0 pxe-service=x86PC, 'Network Boot',pxelinux enable-tftp tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
```

# cat /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default

```
default menu.c32 prompt 0 timeout 30

menu title Raghu's PXE Menu label Install RHEL 7.5 
kernel /networkboot/rhel7/vmlinuz 
append initrd=/networkboot/rhel7/initrd.img inst.repo=ftp://192.168.100.3/pub/rhel7 ks=ftp://192.168.100.3/pub/rhel7/rhel7.cfg


menu title Raghu's PXE Menu of linux label Install app on linux 
kernel /networkboot/my_app/app/vmlinuz 
append initrd=/networkboot/my_app/app/initrd.img inst.repo=ftp://192.168.100.3/pub/app
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you can use Wireshark traffic captures to see what happens a packet level when you boot your PXE client, how the menu is tranfered and displayed at the client and what hapens when you select one of the options of the PXE menu.
At that point you should see the TFTP request of a `kernel` file and immediately after the TFTP request of an `initrd` file.

If those request point to the wrong TFTP IP or to the wrong path or the requested files are missing the whole process stops and you go back to the menu.

You can also see valuable data at the TFTP and proxyDHCP Server logs.